# Handlebars.compile throws an exception 'Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed <html>...'

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, deployd

## Premise

We've got handlebars running in a backend nodejs application for templating various messages that get sent.

### Handlebars.compile throws this exception (when compiling templates from partials)

```
Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed <html>
<head>
... extremely long markup
at Object.compile (/Users/guscrawford/rollick-management-console/deployd/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:501:11)
at HandlebarsEnvironment.hb.compile (/Users/guscrawford/rollick-management-console/deployd/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars.js:39:40)
at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (/Users/guscrawford/rollick-management-console/deployd/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:71:44)
... additional stack trace through to dpd, bluebird etc.
```

### Cannot replicate through isolation

Go ahead and try setting up a scrap project:
`yarn add handlebars handlebars-helper-ternary handlebars-helpers handlebars.numeral`

Then run this script in nodejs:

```
const   handlebars = require('handlebars'),
        numeralHelper = require('handlebars.numeral'),    
        ternaryHelper = require('handlebars-helper-ternary'),
        helpers = require('handlebars-helpers')({
        handlebars: handlebars
    });
console.log(`Testing...`);
const base = `
<html>
    <body style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana,     'sans-serif'; font-size: larger;">
    {{>@partial-block }}
    <td style="text-align: center; padding: 24px;">
    Copyright 2018 My Company, Inc. All rights reserved.

    </body>
</html>

`;
const inner = `
{{#>base}}
    {{subscriber.name}},

    {{member.name}} has received a notifier from {{subscriber.name}}.    

    Click the link below to review!. 
    <a href='{{link}}'>Go!</a>

    Thank you,
    My Company
{{/base}}
`;
numeralHelper.registerHelpers(handlebars);
handlebars.registerHelper('ternary', ternaryHelper);
handlebars.registerHelper("moduloIf", function (index_count, mod, block)     {

    if (index_count > 0 && parseInt(index_count) % (mod) === 0) {
        return block.fn(this);
    } else {
        return block.inverse(this);
    }
});

handlebars.registerHelper("substitute", function(a, options) {
  try {
    function index(obj,i) { return obj ? obj[i] : {} }
    let data = a.split('.').reduce(index, this);
    if (data && typeof data === 'string') return data;
    else return options.fn(this);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('substitute helper:' + e);
  }
});
handlebars.registerPartial('base',base)
var output = handlebars.compile(inner)({name:'Gus'});
console.log('Output:');
console.log(output)
```

### Further consideration

In actuality we have the handlebars `require` wrapped in another module with code run against the handlebars instance as illustrated in the sample script.  We're exporting the handlebars instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The string was a Buffer

Despite logging `typeof` the template string I was passing as a *string*, the output of `readFileAsync` without passing an encoding is a raw node Buffer.

**Duh**

Comment: As I told you, it wasn't a string, a Buffer is not a string. Hence my answer was correct, the error occured on an part of code you didn't show, and I told you what your error was.

Comment: And it's exactly an object that implements a `toString` method containing the raw string, as I described.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear, you're passing something that isn't a string or AST.

[This](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/e1fa3101018064949065696e1955ea99b5cb3e3d/lib/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js#L451) is the only way handlebars throws that error.

```
if (input == null || (typeof input !== 'string' && input.type !== 'Program')) {
    throw new Exception('You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed ' + input);
}
```

You're probably passing an `object`, with a `toString` method, that's why you see:

```
You passed <html>
<head>
... extremely long markup
```

```js
const input = {
  toString() {
    return `<html>
    <head>`;
  }
}
console.log('You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed ' + input);
```

Comment: I've logged a `typeof  handlebars.compile(inner)` and it is certainly a string

Comment: Unless it was overridden, most `toString()` invocations will  output `[Object]` no?

Comment: Are you sure is there where it triggers the error? I'm not seeing the full stacktrace, so I would say you're wrong. Yes, unless overriden, it would be `[Object object]`

Comment: One way to debug, is modify that piece of code that I linked, in `node_modules/handlebars...` put a `console.log` and see exactly what you're sending. But the error is clear, you're sending something that is 100% not a string.

Comment: 1. 100% the `console.log` output of the template passed to `compile` is a string.
2. I realize I removed the markup for brevity but the stack trace clearly begins in `Object.compile > HandlebarsEnvironment.hb.compile > Object.invokePartialWrapper > Object.eval (functions in the stack outside of this I'm pretty confident are not in the scope of handlebars)`

Comment: Can you replicate the error? And give me a snippet that it will trigger it?

Comment: I couldn't replicate it in an isolated package by mirroring my work code-base as closely as possible.  I'm going to further add in dpd to my scrap project and run the script within that context as in the source of the problem but I've not done so yet.

Comment: You're probably passing something that isn't a string to a partial.

Comment: It's something to do with the use of the partials, the other templates without the partial references don't have this problem compiling, and the markup in the stack message is different than the template I logged (the template has the partial references, the one from the stack has the inner content place holder reference in it, I would expect the output to be as the example from the working isolation

Comment: Passing something not a string to a partial... elaborate on that?  How come the exact same templates from my source worked in my scrap project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172414/discussion-between-gus-crawford-and-marcos-casagrande).

Comment: When you register a partial, you're sending something that isn't a string. But the error remains the same, look in your code because you're passing wrong input, and that doesn't happen in the code you gave us.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
const template:Handlebars.TemplateDelegate | null = Handlebars.compile(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(your html document or string));

console.log(template({your_key : "your_value"}))
```

It probably converts a `document` type to an `XML` string representing a DOM tree.
Javascript is a bit hard to deal with.